# Use Java 8 stream to transform nested collection

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have the following nested list:

```
List<List<String>> nestedList = new ArrayList<>();
nestedList.add(Arrays.asList("aM0", "b"));
nestedList.add(Arrays.asList("c", "aM0"));
```

I want to remove "M0" from all the strings. I want to challenge myself using Java 8 stream. The following is what I wrote:

```
nestedList.stream()
  .map(t -> t.stream()
  .map(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf('M')))
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But JDK throws a lot of exceptions. Can anyone tell me how to fix? Or we can not use streams in this special situation? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your real problem is with [`String::substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) so when you use for example :

```
String str = "b";
str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('M'));
```

this will throws :

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 1
```

because `str.indexOf('M')` return `-1`if there is no such occurrence ([`String::indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))) so `str.substring(0, -1)` will fail with that error

---

Instead in such situations its better to use [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) like so :

```
nestedList = nestedList.stream()
        .map(t -> t.stream()
                .map(s -> s.replace("M0", ""))
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Outputs

```
[[a, b], [c, a]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The other simple way is use `replaceAll(UnaryOperator operator)`

```
nestedList.forEach(list->list.replaceAll(s -> s.replace("M0", "")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for quickly spotting the issue. Since after marker 'M', it may not be just '0', I change the code as follows, and it now works:

```
    nestedList.stream().map(t->t.stream().map(s->s.contains("M") ? s.substring(0, s.indexOf('M')) : s).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<String>::new))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Thank you very much for your time to answer my question!